# jquery update data click will bind twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I want that after commit a comment the data gets update.
This is my update function.

```
function renderContent(ret) {
    $(".authorWrap").on('click',function() {
        xqBridge.redirect({
            type: "push",
            url: "users",
            data: ret["owner"]
        })
    });
}
```

click will bind twice.

Could you give any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding "event.stopPropagation()" in your function for "on"

Comment: Are you calling `renderContent` multiple times?

Comment: It seems you're binding the click event on the update function call. Event should be attached first and then it will fire upon update function click. What you're doing is attaching an event on update function which should be attached in advance, may be on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function renderContent(ret) {
$(".authorWrap").on('click',function() {
    xqBridge.redirect({
        type: "push",
        url: "users",
        data: ret["owner"]
    })
});return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the function renderContent twice?

The more advance way is use delegate. 
For example.

```
$(document).on('click','.authorWrap',function(e,ret) {
        xqBridge.redirect({
        type: "push",
        url: "users",
        data: ret["owner"]
    })
    });
```